# How should I be structuring my repository for swift projects?

Tags: ios, swift, git

When I create a Swift project using Xcode I get the .xcodeproj file inside a "ios-app" folder. Currently my repository for this project only has a README and gitignore file in it.

Should I be pushing the entire "ios-app" folder or should I extract the contents of "ios-app" folder (see included image) and push those to the repo?

[image: Contents of "ios-app" folder]

Comment: Don't even worry about it. The way Xcode configures git when you create a project with a git repo is correct.

Comment: Include everything you see there plus any hidden files. Some files and folders in the xcodeproj bundle should be ignored but this should be automatically set up in the hidden .gitignore file if you generated the project using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to run `git init` for the whole parent folder.

However, Xcode included Version Control, most of the functions inside your Xcode Project.

Comment: So do you mean that my git should have the following file/folders: ios-app, .gitignore, readme and not: ios-app, models, pods, ... , gitignore, readme

Comment: @TedLim I don't really understand what you mean. You are not putting files / folders in your "git". You have to initialise git version control via "git init" inside your project root directory. This will create a .git file for you.

Comment: The git repository was already made from github and I'm looking to add the project files that I had before the repository was made

Comment: Ted is asking what should be inside the root folder. I too find the default of my_app_repo/my_app/my_app/actual_files weird.